# How to hide a button after clicking on it,at that time how to make a div visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make a div visible on button click,and I also need to hide the clicked button when the div appears.

Comment: You have to regard what you have tried. In this way, the question may be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code,

```
$('#your_button_id').on('click',function(){
  $('#your_div_id').show();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks For helping me

Comment: i need to hide entire div including the button and make new div visible on same position of the old div

Comment: Then instead of $(this).hide(); you have to give $('#your_div_id_that _to_hide').hide();

Comment: Thanks ,It's Working

Comment: @vishnureji please could you accept the answer if it is working for you.Thank you.

Comment: How Can I put some transition effects on the time of show ??

Comment: Could you please tell me what transistion effect you need. Also tell me to which item you have to apply the effect.

Comment: Transition effect like fade in for the $('#your_div_id').show();

Comment: For that you can refer this link https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp

Comment: Thanks for the reference link

Comment: You can use http://api.jquery.com/fadein/ link as well. Best of luck. Thank you for accepting answer.

Answer (score 1):

To start with you can `hide` the `div` initially and then `hide show` the button and div on button click like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#div").show();
  });

});
```

```css
#div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, button will disappear And A div will appear.</p>

<div id="div"> I am a div </div>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
```

[Read here about jQuery hide() and show()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp)

Comment: Thanks For helping me

Comment: Glad I helped. DO accept the answer for future reference to others :)

Comment: i need to hide entire div including the button and make new div visible on same position of the old div

Answer (score 1):

you can get your answer from this:
[Make one div visible and another invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084674/make-one-div-visible-and-another-invisible)

You can use the display property of style. Intialy set the result section style as

`style = "display:none"`
Then the div will not be visible and there won't be any white space.

Once the search results are being populated change the display property using the java script like

`document.getElementById("someObj").style.display = "block"`
Using java script you can make the div invisible

`document.getElementById("someObj").style.display = "none`

Answer (score 0):

```
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('myId').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('myButton').style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: Thanks For helping me

Comment: i need to hide entire div including the button and make new div visible on same position of the old div

Answer (score 0):

Modified from the [css wc3schools tryit editor site](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_toggleclass)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#desc").toggleClass("blue");
    $("#mybutton").toggleClass("blue");
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.blue {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="desc" class="blue">
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>
<button id="mybutton">Toggle class</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery we can achive this:::

```
**HTML:**
<div class="divClass">  
    My Div Content shows here  
</div>

<button> Click me </button>

**CSS:**
.divClass {
    display: none
}

**JS:**
$('body').on('click', 'button', function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.divClass').show();
});

**Output:** 
https: //jsfiddle.net/cvsraghava/8hg786x9/
```

Comment: Thanks For Helping Me, I have already got the answer from above